# How do I get the class of a BasicObject instance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I have a script that iterates using `ObjectSpace#each_object` with no args. Then it prints how many instances exist for each class.

I realized that some classes redefine the `#class` instance method, so I had to find another way to get the actual class; Let's say it's stored in variable `"klass"`, and `klass === object` is true.

In Ruby 1.8 I could do this, assuming `Object` wasn't monkeypatched:

```
Object.instance_method(:class).bind(object).call
```

This worked for `ActiveSupport::Duration` instances:

```
# Ruby 1.8
# (tries to trick us)
20.seconds.class
=> Fixnum
# don't try to trick us, we can tell
Object.instance_method(:class).bind(20.seconds).call
=> ActiveSupport::Duration
```

But, in Ruby 1.9 this no longer works:

```
# Ruby 1.9
# we are not smart...
Object.instance_method(:class).bind(20.seconds).call
TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of Object
  from (irb):53:in `bind'
  from (irb):53
  from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

It turns out that `ActiveSupport::Duration` subclasses `ActiveSupport::BasicObject`. The latter is made to subclass `::BasicObject` in Ruby 1.9, so `Object` is excluded from the inheritance chain. This doesn't, and can't, happen in Ruby 1.8, so `ActiveSupport::BasicObject` is a subclass of `Object`.

I haven't found any way to detect the actual class of a Ruby 1.9 object that isn't an instance of `Object`. `BasicObject` in 1.9 is really bare-bones:

```
BasicObject.instance_methods
=> [:==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__]
```

Ideas?

UPDATE:

Since ruby 1.9 reached end-of-life, I'm changing my accept to @indirect's answer. The mentions of ruby 1.9 above are merely for historical purposes, to show that the change from 1.8 to 1.9 was the original cause of my problem.

Comment: I had the same problem once and I gave up. There are a [few approaches](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/7e35b392a0b78768) but either didn't work for me or were too intrusive. Maybe you can redefine your question and point directly to want you are looking for in the origin and not trying to make one of the possible approaches to work.

Comment: @fguillen Thanks for the link. The post about using self.inherited looks promising.

Comment: Accepted Frederick Cheung's answer. I chose it over my solution because it probably performs better. Others may have different requirements or constraints - just upvote whichever one you like.

Comment: Switched acceptance to paon's answer. It doesn't depend on external libs, and the only downside is that it allocates the eigenclass on every BasicObject you call it on. The only change I'd make would be to define the method as `__realclass__` instead of `class`.

Comment: FYI: see my new answer based on paon's solution. I kept the acceptance on paon's because the core idea was his.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can upgrade to Ruby 2.0, you don't need to implement anything at all:

```
>> Kernel.instance_method(:class).bind(BasicObject.new).call
=> BasicObject
```

Comment: +1 Any links to info on why this works? `BasicObject` doesn't include `Kernel`, so why can a `Kernel` method be bound to it?

Comment: A similar trick would be: (class << BasicObject.new; self; end).superclass

Comment: +1, pure Ruby awesomeness, no need for anything else + this works for anything sub-classed from BasicObject. Agree with @Kelvin though, be nice to see why this works.

Comment: Answer to @Kelvin's question: It appears that all module methods can be bound to _any_ object in this way. The source of MRI [UnboundMethod#bind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) includes a guard clause to throw errors which begins: `if (!RB_TYPE_P(methclass, T_MODULE) &&...` before it goes on to test whether the object is `kind_of?` the unbound method's 'owner' class - nice to know.

Comment: Thanks @MatzFan . So the `bind` enforcement is weaker in ruby 2.x. I wonder what the rationale was behind this change.

Answer (score 13):

The following solution refers to the superclass of the eigenclass. As a consequence, it has the **side effect** of allocating the eigenclass (detectable by `ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]` in MRI). But since `BasicObject#class`  is only invoked on blank slate objects (i.e. objects that are not kind-of `Object`, i.e. that are not `Object`*s*) the side effect also applies just for blank slate objects. For `Object`*s*,
the standard `Kernel#class` is invoked.

```
class BasicObject
  def class
    (class << self; self end).superclass
  end
end

# tests:
puts RUBY_VERSION               # 1.9.2
class B < BasicObject; end
class X;               end
p BasicObject.new.class             # BasicObject
p B          .new.class             # B
p X          .new.class             # X
p               6.class             # Fixnum
p B.instance_method(:class).owner   # BasicObject
p X.instance_method(:class).owner   # Kernel
p          6.method(:class).owner   # Kernel
```

Edit - Note:
Indeed, there is an issue with `ActiveSupport::Duration`. This class uses interception (`method_missing`) for redirecting messages to the `:value` attribute. As a consequence, it provides false introspection for its instances. To preserve this falsity, it is necessary to use another name for the class map, e.g. the proposed `__realclass__`. Thus, the modified solution might look like this:

```
class BasicObject
  def __realclass__; (class << self; self end).superclass end
end
class Object; alias __realclass__ class end
```

Another way of not invoking `class << self` on `Object`s is via `Module#===`, as suggested by Kelvin on this page.

Comment: This is pure genius... It can even be defined after all libs are loaded. But you should define a different method name like `__realclass__`, otherwise `20.seconds.class` won't return Fixnum -- that can break a lot of code. If you do that, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Btw, I tried using `singleton_class.superclass` instead, but I got `TypeError: can't define singleton`. Guess BasicObject's are weird like that.

Comment: @Kelvin: `Fixnum`s (as well as other immediate values: `false`, `true`, `nil`, and `Symbol`s) are not blank slate objects so that `Kernel#class` gets invoked for them as before. Using `singleton_class` does not work because it is an instance method of `Kernel`.

Comment: @Kelvin: +1 for the `::Object === self` test. I did not know that `Module#===` is the inverse of `Kernel#kind_of?`.

Comment: I just realized why this works. It's because the singleton class is a `Class` instance. `Class` is a subclass of `Object`, which is why the `superclass` method is defined on instances. When the singleton gets created, the `BasicObject` subclass is set as its superclass. Weird ruby magic!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about doing it in Ruby, but this is straightforward using the C API to Ruby. The RubyInline Gem makes adding bits of C to your Ruby code quite easy:

```
require 'inline'
class Example
  inline do |builder|  
    builder.c_raw_singleton <<SRC, :arity => 1
      VALUE true_class(VALUE self, VALUE to_test) {
        return rb_obj_class(to_test);
      }
SRC
   end
end
```

And then:

```
1.9.2p180 :033 > Example.true_class(20.minutes)
 => ActiveSupport::Duration
```

Comment: This is quite elegant and doesn't seem to interfere with other parts the app. I've upvoted but need to consider a bit more before accepting.

Comment: Btw, I thought it might be possible to something similar in FFI, but I didn't see a way to convert a ruby object into a VALUE pointer  and vice-versa.

Comment: There seems to be a minor bug in RubyInline - once the ~/.ruby_inline directory is created, then I can't define any more inline functions in irb. Inline is trying to get the mtime of '(irb)'. Loading it from an external file works fine.

Answer (score 5):

fguillen's link made me think of this way.

Pros:

1. It doesn't need external libraries.

Cons:

1. It must be executed before loading any classes that subclass BasicObject.
2. It adds a method to every new class

.

```
class BasicObject
  def self.inherited(klass)
    klass.send(:define_method, :__realclass__) { klass }
  end
  def __realclass__
    BasicObject
  end
end

# ensures that every Object will also have this method
class Object
  def __realclass__
    Object.instance_method(:class).bind(self).call
  end
end

require 'active_support/core_ext'

20.seconds.__realclass__  # => ActiveSupport::Duration

# this doesn't raise errors, so it looks like all objects respond to our method
ObjectSpace.each_object{|e| e.__realclass__ }
```

Comment: As I read the question, I was also thinking of an `inherited` hook... nice code, I like it!

Answer (score 3):

This is my modification of @paon's answer:

Reasoning behind the changes:

- Method name doesn't clash with existing libs, e.g. the
  `ActiveSupport::Duration` instance behavior `2.seconds.class` remains
  `Fixnum`.
- Since `Object` doesn't have its own `__realclass__` method, we want to avoid allocating the eigenclass for those instances. @paon's original answer did this inherently by defining the `class` method name.

---

```
class BasicObject
  def __realclass__
    ::Object === self ?
      # Note: to be paranoid about Object instances, we could 
      # use Object.instance_method(:class).bind(s).call.
      self.class :
      (class << self; self end).superclass
  end
end

# test
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric'

duration = 2.seconds
string = 'hello world'
p duration.class  # => Fixnum
p string.class    # => String
GC.start
p ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]  # => 566

# creates the eigenclass
p duration.__realclass__  # => ActiveSupport::Duration
p ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]  # => 567

# doesn't create the eigenclass
p string.__realclass__  # => String
p ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]  # => 567
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(class << object; self; end).superclass
```

Comment: True, but this is really the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a `BasicKernel` module via duplication of the `Kernel` module and subsequent removal of all methods except the `class` method. The `BasicKernel` is included into the `BasicObject` class (just like `Kernel` is included into `Object`).

In `req_methods`, you can specify arbitrary subset of `Kernel` methods to be preserved.

```
class BasicObject
  include ::BasicKernel = ::Kernel.dup.module_eval {
    v = $VERBOSE
    $VERBOSE = nil               # suppress object_id warning
    req_methods = [:class]       # required methods (to be preserved)
    all_methods = public_instance_methods +
               protected_instance_methods +
                 private_instance_methods
    all_methods.each { |x| remove_method(x) unless req_methods.include?(x) }
    $VERBOSE = v
    self
  }
end

# tests:
puts RUBY_VERSION               # 1.9.2
class B < BasicObject; end
class X;               end
p BasicObject.new.class           # BasicObject
p B          .new.class           # B
p X          .new.class           # X
p B.instance_method(:class).owner # BasicKernel
p X.instance_method(:class).owner # Kernel
p Object.ancestors                # [Object, Kernel, BasicObject, BasicKernel]
p BasicKernel.instance_methods    # [:class]
```

Edit: See the Note in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216927/641718

Comment: This is a nice concept, but doesn't address the `ActiveSupport::Duration` issue, e.g. `2.seconds.class` *should* return Fixnum.

Answer (score 0):

For the similar situation where you simply want a class you created that inherits from `BasicObject` to support the `#class` method, you can copy the method over from `Kernel`.

```
class Foo < BasicObject
  define_method(:class, ::Kernel.instance_method(:class))
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.class
=> Foo
```