# Copy method from one class to another

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, proc

I want to write small class with some methods, which actualy belongs to other classes, so how can I define methods in other classes which are copies of existing. I believe it is metaprogramming magi I don't understand.

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    # with blocks, I would just pass block, but this is methods
    # so this won't work
    Bar.class_eval(perform)
    Bar.class_eval(process)
    Bar.class_eval(save)
  end

  def perform
    1+1
  end

  def process
    # some code
  end

  def save
    # some code
  end
end

class Bar; end

foo = Foo.new
foo.perform
#=> 2
Bar.test
#=> 1
```

Why I need this? I am working on gem which takes a class with just three methods. On initializing (which ill be hidden in parent class) it will pass this methods to different classes. I can make this with blocks, but with methods it is little cleaner.

**PS**: It is like copying methods from one class to another

**PSS**: Or... how to convert method to proc, so I can pass it to `class_eval`

Comment: maybe you must to use delegation? http://khelll.com/blog/ruby/delegation-in-ruby/

Comment: Can't you just include a module?

Comment: @Fivell, maybe! I need to read about delegation right now

Comment: added link with examples

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev in this case - no

Comment: @Fivell, mmm no. Because methods are undefined in those classes. User just defines three methods in his abstract class (which inherits from Base class) and thats all he do. Then metaprogramming magick should define this methods in those classes User don't know about

Comment: why don't you want just use inheritence? Bar < Foo

Comment: Are "the classes User doesn't know about" generated dynamically? Or do you want to "copy" the methods to a certain fixed class?

Comment: Because this three methods belongs to different classes

Comment: @Alex D I want to copy them to two fixed classes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To convert a method to something which can be called like a Proc, use `obj.method(:method_name)`. That will give you a *bound* Method object, which when `call`ed, will be invoked on `obj`. If you want to invoke it on a different object of the same class, you can call `method.unbind.bind(different_obj)`.

That still doesn't allow you to "copy" methods from one class to another. If you want to allow the user to pass a class which defines 3 methods, rather than passing 3 blocks, it might work better if you store a reference to that class (or an instance of it) internally, and call methods on it as required. That's what the person who commented about "delegation" meant.

OR, you can let the user pass a Module, and make your own class `include` or `extend` the module (as required).

Comment: I believe I will use reference :) But now I am interested if I can copy methods between classes in Ruby!

Comment: I don't think there is, but if you find a way, please post it. I'd like to know too.

Comment: I believed that metaprogramming can do everything :)
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to copy methods from one class to another, but there is a major caveat: the destination class must be a kind_of? the source class, or the source must be a module. This restriction is partially documented in the docs for [UnboundMethod#bind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind]), but to see the module exception you have to look at the source code for the method. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18621313/830254) contains more discussion on the topic.

Here is an example:

```
module A
  def say_hello
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

class B
  define_method(:say_hello, A.instance_method(:say_hello))
end

b = B.new
b.say_hello
=> Hello
```

This would also work if `A` was a class and `B` was a class that inherited from `A`. But in that case, you would have already gotten the method through inheritance, so I don't personally see a use for it.

The one situation where I have found this pattern useful is when designing DSL's using objects that inherit from `BasicObject`. Since `BasicObject` doesn't `include Kernel` like `Object` does, you don't have easy access to a lot of useful methods like `#instance_variables` or even `#class`. But you can copy them individually from Kernel into your class:

```
class Foo < BasicObject
  define_method(:class, ::Kernel.instance_method(:class))
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.class
=> Foo
```