# Implement Ruby's Object#class method

Tags: ruby

I'm extending `BasicObject`, and I'd like to implement `Object#class` method. I'm not sure how to do this other than hard-coding the return value like this:

```
class MyObject < BasicObject
  def class
    ::Kernel::eval "::MyObject"
  end
end

MyObject.new.class
#=> MyObject
```

With this solution, any class that inherits from `MyObject` would have to overwrite this method in order to keep it accurate. Is there a better way?

Comment: @falsetru: This totally works! I was actually working on something similar but I wasn't quite there yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to implement this method in Ruby. You need access to three things that you cannot access from Ruby:

- the class pointer
- the superclass pointer
- the virtual class flag (include classes and singleton classes are virtual classes)

`Object#class` works something like this:

```
class Object
  def class
    c = self.__class__
    c = c.__superclass__ while c.__virtual__?
    c
  end
end
```

There's also `Class#superclass`:

```
class Class
  def superclass
    c = self.__superclass__
    c = c.__superclass__ while c.__virtual__?
    c
  end
end
```

And since there is no way to get the class pointer (remember: the `class` method does *not* return it) and there is no way to get the superclass pointer (remember: the `superclass` method doesn't return it either) and there is no way for you to check whether a class is virtual, it is impossible to write this method in Ruby.

You need some sort of privileged access to the runtime internals to do that.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @DesAdams: BTW: when I said "you need privileged access to the runtime internals", it's of course possible that those runtime internals *are* actually exposed to you as Ruby methods, so you *could* potentially write `class` in Ruby … however you would then be calling interpreter-specific APIs that are not part of the Ruby Language Specification, and thus your code wouldn't be portable. In Rubinius, for example, it is probably possible to do what you ask, but it wouldn't work on any other implementation, because you would be calling Rubinius-specific APIs.

Comment: @Priti: I don't understand how that is relevant to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are refusing to inherit `Object`, you are missing almost all basic methods, including `class` or `ancestors`. You would need to hard code everything. Besides the minimal syntax, everything is gone. Think of it as tabla rasa. There is no other method on which you can build your methods.

Ruby is designed to have all objects inherit from `Object`, and going against that does not result in useful result.

Answer (score 0):

I was directed towards this possible duplicate question: [How do I get the class of a BasicObject instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197586/how-do-i-get-the-class-of-a-basicobject-instance)

The solution provided to that question solves my problem. Thanks!